# Remove space and underscore between link and text

Tags: html, css

I've this snipped for which I want to remove the space between the link and the upcoming text, but I can't figure our how to do it. I've tried using `padding` and `margin`, but nothing works.

HTML:

```
A <a href="#" style="letter-spacing: 1em;">link</a>. Some text.
```

Output:

[image]

Here's is an example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPQVXx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Although this answer has been accepted, I do not recommend using it. It breaks in some browsers and won't be compatible with screen-readers. Besides that, it is also bad practice to just flip letters around. I've created this answer to show some of the possibilities, not as a good solution**

That being said. [Here it is](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjGXqr).

It does require some extra effort, but it works without the use of negative margins or extra html.

You basically have to swap all the letters around, and you're good to go!

This works because of the use of two things. `letter-direction` and `:first-letter`.

```
a{
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: 1em;
  direction: rtl;
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}

a:first-letter{
  letter-spacing: 0;
}
```

This would've been much easier with a `:last-letter`selector :)

Hope this helps

Comment: Aha, that worked. How good is the browser support, do you know? +1

Comment: `:first letter`, as well as the `direction` property are completely supported by all major browsers. `:first letter` has been here since CSS1, and `direction` since CSS2

Comment: @Oleander I'd hate to be a screen reader reading your backwards links!

Comment: I thought something like this too, but [looks horrible on Firefox](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7BVhh.png) and [doesn't work as desired on Chrome](http://i.stack.imgur.com/i7UTW.png) neither. It works great on IE and Edge, though.

Comment: I've altered my answer. It shouldn't be accepted, to be honest

Answer (score 2):

You could try removing the letter-spacing on the last letter of the word.

```
A <a href="#" style="letter-spacing: 1em;">lin<span style="letter-spacing: 0;">k</span></a>. Some text.
```

It's not a neat solution, but if it's a one-off it'll get the job done. If not for the underline from the link, a negative right margin equal to the letter spacing would have done the trick as well.

Comment: I don't really like this solution. The space *after* the word must be a common problem and therefore also be possible to solve in a proper way.

Comment: @oleander After a little google search i found this page which discusses your problem also. Good to know if you need a solution that is not a one-off https://iamsteve.me/blog/entry/remove-letter-spacing-from-last-letter

Comment: @Oleander You would think so wouldn't you? Like i said, it just depends on how often you will have this issue and what type of application you are using. If this is the only place you need ot do it, and it's not something that is going to be changed or editable (like in a cms) then it is a perfectly fine solution. Otherwise you'll need to find a better, more scalable solution.

Comment: I assumed that most hacks were fixed with CSS3, but that might not be the case when I read all the suggestions I got. Thanks for your effort tho, I think this would be the best solution, even tho it's not perfect. +1

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is a clear violation of the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#letter-spacing).

> A given value of [`letter-spacing`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#letter-spacing) only affects the spacing
>   between characters completely contained within the element for which
>   it is specified:
>
> ```css
> p    { letter-spacing: 1em; }
> span { letter-spacing: 2em; }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <p>a<span>bb</span>c</p>
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> This also means that applying [`letter-spacing`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#letter-spacing) to an element
>   containing only a single character has no effect on the rendered
>   result:
>
> ```css
> p    { letter-spacing: 1em; }
> span { letter-spacing: 2em; }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <p>a<span>b</span>c</p>
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> An inline box only includes letter spacing between characters
>   completely contained within that element:
>
> ```css
> p    { letter-spacing: 1em; }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <p>a<span>bb</span>c</p>
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> It is incorrect to include the letter spacing on the right or trailing
>   edge of the element:
>
> [image]

You only have to wait until browsers fix this. I suggest against fixing it with hacks like negative margins because it will backfire when browsers implement the standard behavior.

Comment: Good answer, thanks. I dont think this will be solved anytime soon, but it's good to know that it's not suppose to work like this. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
A <a href="#" style="letter-spacing: 1em;">lin</a><a href="#">k</a>. Some text
```

This is ugly, but it does the trick.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3d5xzups/)

Comment: What? Where's the link? -1

Comment: Sorry, had to edit the answer. Let me give you a jsfiddle link. Don't be so quick to -1 me, sheesh. lol

Comment: Removed the -1. This is the same answer as partypete25 gave. See my comment on his answer.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Yeah, we posted at the same time. I will think about it a bit more, Like I said, it's not pretty. If all else fails you can make both href's the same link. I'll get back to you if I think of anything cleaner.

Comment: @Oleander It's not the same as my answer, I've used a span to style text, not added an extra link. Very different.

Comment: Yeah, I just saw that. True.

Comment: Sorry, it isn't, but it's the same idea. +1

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
    A <a href="#" ><span style="letter-spacing: 1em;">lin</span>k</a>. Some text.
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this one:

```
A <a href="#" style="letter-spacing: 1em;">lin<span>k</span></a>. Some text.
```

**CSS**

```
span{
  letter-spacing: 0;
}
```

[**HERE MY DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/jxu3j6gu/1/)